# Get tag attribute for matching inner word in regex

Tags: python, html, regex

I need to get a particular attribute value from a tag whose inner word matches my query word. For example, consider a target html-

```html
<span data-attr="something" attr1="" ><i>other_word</i></span>
<span data-attr="required" attr1="" ><i>word_to_match</i></span>
<span data-attr="something1" attr1="" ><i>some_other_word</i></span>
```

Now, I need to get the '**required**' value from the **data-attr** attribute for the tag where the inner word(in this case **word_to_match**) matches my query word.

The problem is that the regexes that I'm writing are returning the other spans as well. I haven't been able to make a non greedy regex in this case.

If it helps, I'm doing this in python and kindly no "don't use regex here" solutions.

Comment: Why no HTML parser solution? Homework? :) You see, if you need a regex solution for HTML input, you *must* explain why. Such answers get downvoted, thus, I stay away (usually) from answering such questions.

Comment: Are you searching for a single regex or can you break it up into two steps?

Comment: Ok, I will post in a comment: [`data-attr=(['"]?)((?:(?!\1)[^>])*)[^<]*['"]?(?=[^>]*>\s*<i[^>]*>word_to_match</)`](https://regex101.com/r/qC1cG5/1). But it is up to you to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Because, like I said, in the context where I need to solve this, we cant use an external module like pyQuery.. hence regex..

Comment: @scorreia any solutions are welcome...

Comment: Here is my messy contribution, it's possible you may need to clean it up depending on your needs: https://regex101.com/r/oI3iG1/1

Answer (score 0):

What about using string replace with regex and output group (javascript syntax, but I expect python has a similar function)?

```
str.replace(/data-attr="([^"]*)"[^>]*>[^<]*<i>word_to_match</, '$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing websites with regex is not a good idea. You may you use BeautifulSoup. It is reliable and efficient:

```
>>>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>>soup = BeautifulSoup("""
    <span data-attr="something" attr1="" ><i>other_word</i></span>
    <span data-attr="required" attr1="" ><i>word_to_match</i></span>
    <span data-attr="something1" attr1="" ><i>some_other_word</i></span>""")

>>>[x.attrs['data-attr'] for x in soup.select('span') if 'word_to_match' in str(x)][0]
'required'
```

Comment: what if these spans are engulfed by a parent span? only the specific span needs to get selected .. presence or absence of a parent span element cannot be guaranteed..

Comment: It is unusual in web pages <spam>...<spam> ... </spam>...</spam> construction. In any case BeautifulSoup features able to handle it, just more information needed.